# How to receive JSON data in ASMX web service

Tags: c#, asmx

I'm trying to write an ASMX web service to receive a block of JSON data from elsewhere (meaning I have no control over the format of the data - it's documented and consistent, but outside my control).  As a test, I've created a simple webpage that sends that same data via an AJAX request.  The data is definitely attached as the payload of my POST request:
[Picture of chrome devtools showing payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nASGR.png)

But when I try to receive that data in my ASMX webservice, I get an empty string:

```
  [WebMethod]
  public string UpdateProjectImage() 
  {
    using (var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream))
    {
      string json = sr.ReadToEnd(); // this comes out as an empty string!
      return json;
    }
  }
```

Please note that this is being built with VS 2012 and IIS 7.5 running on Win2008R2, and I cannot change the technology stack.

The streamreader technique ought to work, because I copied it from another webservice that's working - but it doesn't work in this case (it just gives me an empty string), and I don't know why.  It's probably some weird configuration setting, but I just don't know what setting it might be.

Comment: Have you run the debugger to find the `sr.EndOfStream` or the stream's `Position` before your read call?

Comment: sr.EndOfStream is "true" before the "ReadToEnd()" call.  The "Position" isn't directly accessible, but I found it buried inside the stream object, where it has a value of 194 (which happens to be the length of the JSON data).  So it's as if something in magic-microsoft-land has already read the data.  Is there a way to tell it not to read it?  Or a way to "rewind" the stream?

Comment: How are you calling the asmx code? using ajax?

Comment: You can reset the position https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.position?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: That did it! - the stream object doesn't have a position, but if I set sr.BaseStream.Position = 0, then the "sr.ReadToEnd()" call gives me all of the data.  THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I have to set sr.BaseStream.Position = 0 before the call to sr.ReadToEnd(). I'm not 100% it's the "right" solution (I've done this elsewhere and I didn't need to set the position, and it just seems weird to have to do that), but it's working now and that's good enough for me.

Special thanks to Jasen for pointing me in the right direction.